# smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at... al intentar enviar un correo electrónico desde shell usando django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electrónico desde shell usando django, pero no me permite. Me sale un error.

Esta es la configuración de mi código

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"

EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

EMAIL_PORT=587

EMAIL_HOTS_USER="micorreo@gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOTS_PASSWORD= "mi_contraseña_de_aplicaciones_de_16_caracteres_en_gmail"
```

Ya en el shell ejecuto

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail

>>> send_mail('Asunto', 'Mensaje', 'micorreo@gmail.com',['correodestino@hotmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

¡¡¡Y aquí todo el error!!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 131, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 149, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 887, in sendmail  
 raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f5-20020a05620a280500b006ce76811a07sm648994qkp.75 - gsmtp', 'micorreo@gmail.com')
```

¿Podrían por favor indicarme cuál es el problema? Ya que tengo todo configurado en gmail (verificación en dos pasos y contraseña de aplicaciones), pero me sigue saliendo este error.

Comment: pero podria desactivarlo para probar que me dices tu, en tal caso ese correo solo lo cree para hacer pruebas asi que no tengo problemas en desactivarlo porque solo lo uso para probar

Comment: ok voy a probar ya te comento si me funciono esperame unos segundos por favor

Comment: Según el enlace en tu mensaje de error `https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError`, Te falta prender SSL (según ellos, debes habilitar ambos, SSL y TLS)

Comment: no me deja crear contraseña de aplicaciones, cuando desactivo verificacion en dos pasos.

Comment: @Alfabravo y como habilito eso podrias por favor indicarme

Comment: @FranciscoJavier si ya eso lo tenia hecho incluso la contraseña es de 16 digitos pero el error seguia saliendo

Comment: Tienes `EMAIL_HOTS_USER` y es `EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Comment: @Alfabravo no me habia percatado en eso gracias voy a probar ya te cuento dame 2 minutos para probar

Comment: @Alfabravo y el HOST del pass esta mal tambien no me habia percatado voy a cambiar y pruebo

Comment: @Alfabravo ahora cambio de error

Comment: @Alfabravo copie lao ultimo del error ::.....     File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Comment: Por favor, tratemos de no extender los comentarios como chat (que no son un chat) y, si algún comentario te mueve en alguna dirección, [edit] la pregunta y AÑADIR LA NUEVA INFO son el camino a seguir. Mira que en los comentarios no se leen bien los logs. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo te entiendo y me disculpo soy nuevo en esto ante todos

Comment: @Alfabravo HERMANO MUCHAS GRACIAS LA SOLUCION ERA LO QUE ME COMENTASTES DEL HOST  DIOS TE BENDIGA YA HACE EL ENVIO DEL CORREO.. GRACIAS HERMANO

Comment: Con mucho gusto ;)

Comment: Y gracias a todos tambien por el aporte de sus conocimientos tambien muchas gracias a todos Dios los Bendiga!!

Answer (score -1):

lo que pasa es que gmail se puso un poco estricto con el tema de envíos de correos por aplicaciones externas te recomiendo hacer una cuenta en gmx ahí son menos estrictos con ese tema o en yahoo te dejo un script que me ha funcionado para el envió de correos a través de python 3

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


correo_electronico = "correo electronico"
password_correo = "tu contraseña"
nombre_remitente = "nombre del remitente"


server = smtplib.SMTP("mail.gmx.com", 587)
print("Comenzo el Envio")
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(correo_electronico,password_correo)
 
 
  
fromaddr = nombre_remitente + '<' +correo_electronico+'>' 
toaddr = "correo al que se desea enviar el mensaje"
subject = "From Python"
  
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = subject
print("Procesando") 
body = """

<h1>plantilla html a enviar  </h1>

"""
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
print('Mensaje enviado')
```

Comment: gracias voy a probar

Comment: Cualquier servicio SMTP va a permitir enviar emails (es su único trabajo). No suena saludable resolver usando una opción menos segura o confiable. Y al final, no resuelve la pregunta que tenemos todos de por qué al OP no le funciona su script ;)

Comment: Yo estoy presentando algo, dime de que sirve tu comentario, a caso ayuda. no lo creo